# How to use virtual keyword in case of multilevel inheritance

Tags: c#, c++, oop

I was going through Virtual methods and was not able to find how to use them in case of multi level inheritance. Also why do we need virtual if we can simple create objects of each class and call its methods.
Thanks already.

Comment: Do you want to add a language specific tag to this question?

Comment: @P.W Thanks, I somehow forgot to mention it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is applicable for C++ only.
The [**`virtual`**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/virtual) keyword in C++ is used to effect [runtime-polymorphism](https://www.quora.com/What-exactly-is-the-runtime-polymorphism-in-C++). The number of levels in an inheritance hierarchy does not matter. Whether it is two or twenty, if a class method in the base class is marked as `virtual`, then it is `virtual` in all the derived classes.

In C++, there is another keyword **[`override`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override)** which is used to mark the methods in the derived classes as having overridden an implementation of a base class method.